# What apps are available for use with a touchscreen?

Tags: software-recommendation, touchscreen

What apps are there to download from the Ubuntu Software Center that have been developed with a touchscreen in mind?

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years making this question seem abandoned. Question itself is 5+ years old making it about an EOL Ubuntu version. Although question could be closed as `too broad` because it asks about ALL touchscreen apps today, VTC as `not reproducible` given the point in time question was asked.